# How to do double buffering in C++ Builder 2010?

Tags: c++, doublebuffered, c++builder-2010

I have a code that continuously draws lines. The problem is that the lines keep flickering every time form is refreshed. I heard I should use double buffering, but how to do it? I'm using c++ builder 2010. Here is my code:

```
void __fastcall TForm2::PaintBox1Paint(TObject *Sender)
{
Form2->Refresh();
TPoint P;
::GetCursorPos( &P );
P = ScreenToClient( P );
int XX;
int YY;
if (P.x<240)
{
  XX=15;
  YY= ((445-P.y)*(XX-P.x)/(240-P.x)+P.y);
}
else if(P.x==240)
{
  XX=240;YY=-5;
}
else
{
  XX=465;
  YY= ((445-P.y)*(XX-P.x)/(240-P.x)+P.y);
}
int delta=2*(445-YY);
this->Canvas->MoveTo(241,445);
this->Canvas->LineTo(XX,YY);
while(0<YY&&YY<480&&YY!=445)
{
  XX=abs(480-XX);
  YY-=delta;
  this->Canvas->LineTo(XX,YY);
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Certainly you need to remove the call to `Form2->Refresh`. That asks the form to repaint itself immediately. That cannot help.

Secondly, your code handles the `OnPaint` event of a `TPaintBox` control. You are expected to paint on the canvas of `TPaintBox` rather than the form's canvas. Change all references to `this->Canvas` to instead refer to `PaintBox1->Canvas`. You may also need to correct the coordinates used to when painting.

Alternatively you could keep your existing code, and remove the paint box altogether. In which case take your current code and attach it to the form's `OnPaint` handler instead.

As for double buffering, you could let the VCL do it for you. Set the form's `DoubleBuffered` property to `true`. That is all you need to do, although be warned that it can have undesirable consequences on the visual appearance of certain control in certain themes. Be alert for any problems.

If you want to do the double buffering your self it is easy enough. Create a `TBitmap`. Set its size appropriately. Draw your lines to the `Canvas` of the bitmap. Then draw the bitmap onto the paint box canvas, or the form's canvas.

Comment: Okay, makes sense! But what should I replace `Form2->Refresh` with? I used the method of deleting the paintbox.

Comment: You don't need to replace it with anything. Somewhere else in your program you call `Invalidate`, either on paint box, or form if you abandon paint box. That forces a paint cycle. I suggest you need to read up on how painting works. Specifically WM_PAINT and InvalidateRect. Petzold's book is where most of us started.